Why does chrome sometimes need to change the DNS in order to access the website properly?
I'm from China, is it because the GFW is blocking some chrome services?
But I use "Proxy SwitchyOmega
2.5.21" blacklist filters websites so that they are accessible via V2rayN, isn't chrome accessible via V2rayN?
As the title says, my attempts to switch DNS sometimes work, but sometimes it doesn't
Whenever a problem arises, no matter whether it is a legitimate website in China, it cannot be opened
I don't have any of these problems with Firefox
